# Facing issue while converting NSString to NSURL

Tags: objective-c, assetslibrary

I have an assets library url to a photo:
"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=8D4D7820-EDD6-4CA4-A44A-2ACD53A112FC&ext=JPG"
I have this in a string property imgURLString.
I am trying to convert this to NSURL in the following way:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.imgURLString];
```

However, I am getting an exception:

```
[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa8281f0
```

I am sure I have the above mentioned string in self.imgURLString and it is not trying to convert an empty string. So why am I getting this exception and how do I solve it?

I am basically trying to convert the string to an NSURL to fetch the photo using the assets library url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.imgURLString` is actually already an `NSURL`, not an `NSString`. You are assigning the asset URL (an `NSURL`) to your `NSString` property. Change your property to be an `NSURL`.